# How Smart-gwt SC.askforValue() cancel can be handled?

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

**My Question:**

In the code below I try to ask user a value. `SC.askforValue()` is called with all possible variables, a `Dialog` is given as parameter to adjust the dialog.

My problem is what happens, when user presses cancel? On my current smartGwt version (2.1), is it possible to see the cancel alone? Now empty value and cancel get both handled in the same way.

**My Code:**

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
dialog.setWidth(200);

SC.askforValue("myTitle", "myQuestion", "defaultValue", new ValueCallback() {

   @Override
   public void execute(String value) {
        if (value != null) {
        // do sth.
        } else {
        /* cancel pressed / empty value. */
        }
       }
}, dialog);
```

Comment: I saw on the API of Dialog, that there is a cancelClick() that could be overridden, but what kind of code needs to go there? Maybe in that case also okClick() needs to be overridden.. How that relates then to callback? That is the tricky part on that solution path..

Comment: Overriding the clicks on Dialog did not help, Callback gets executed anyways. I would like to know which button is pressed on dialog, but still don't know how..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/util/SC.html#askforValue%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20com.smartgwt.client.util.ValueCallback,%20com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Dialog%29),

if you want to differantiate blank input and cancel event, you can check the value, you receive in the callback. When user has entered nothing and clicks OK, blank string will be there as value. And when user clicks Cancel, the value will be null.

Comment: I have an older version of smart, there is a 4.0 already, we have 2.1. and of course in our case the return for empty string is also null. If no other solution appears, I'll accept this, because the implicit solution with this added comment is that I'll have to update my smart to get this right.